# Send mass SMTP emails is slow and give error after sending 10-12 emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient, mass-emails

I am sending SMTP email using code:

```
protected void btnSendEmailToAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = Master.User;

    //Create a temporary DataTable
    DataTable dtCustomers = new DataTable();
    dtCustomers.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("email",typeof(string)), new DataColumn("EmailSentOn",typeof(string)) });

    //Copy the Checked Rows to DataTable
    foreach (GridViewRow row in Grid.Rows)
    {
        // Only look in data rows, ignore header and footer rows
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkrow");

            if (ChkBoxRows.Checked == true)
            {
                string Name = (row.FindControl("lblname") as Label).Text.ToLower();

                dtCustomers.Rows.Add(Name, (row.FindControl("lblemail") as Label).Text, (row.FindControl("lblEmailsentOn") as Label).Text);

                var id = Grid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
                using (var db = new DatabaseHelper())
                {
                    db.ExecNonQuery(Queries.UpdateReminderEmailSentData, "@RW", id);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    string subject = "My Subject";

    //Using Parallel Multi-Threading send multiple bulk email.
    Parallel.ForEach(dtCustomers.AsEnumerable(), row =>
    {
        string body = this.PopulateBody(row["name"].ToString(), row["EmailSentOn"].ToString(), username);
        SendMassEmail(row["email"].ToString(), subject, body.ToString());
    });

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Email Sent Successfully')", true);
    BindGrid();
}
```

PopulateBody fuction:

```
private string PopulateBody(string name, string date, string username)
{
    string body = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/followupemailtemplate.html")))
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    body = body.Replace("{Name}", name);
    body = body.Replace("{Date}", date);
    body = body.Replace("{UserName}", username);

    return body;
}
```

SendMassEmail Function:

```
private bool SendMassEmail(string recipient, string subject, string body)
{
    var smtp = new SmtpClient()
    {
        Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"],//smtp.gmail.com
        EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]),//true
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]),
        Port = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"])//587
    };
    using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
    {
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], "My Email");
        mailMessage.Subject = subject;
        mailMessage.Body = body;                    
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient));
        smtp.Send(mailMessage);
    }
    return true;
}
```

It takes 30s to send five emails:(

I tried using Threads like(even i have been suggested that there's no need to use threads if we are using parallel.foreach):

```
Thread T1 = new Thread(delegate ()
            {
                using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
                {
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], "My Email");
                    mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                    mailMessage.Body = ShowBody;
                    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recepientEmail));

                 smtp.Send(mailMessage);                   
                }
        });
T1.Start();
```

That is fast but not send all email some gone unsent.

i.e. after sending 10-12 emails or sometimes even less it throws exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException'
>   occurred in System.dll Additional information: Service not available,
>   closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary
>   System Problem. Try again later (WS). u12sm5363862pfg.146 - gsmtp

Don't know whats wrong. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Plz dont mark it duplicate or anything as i searched lot solutions but coudn't find correct one.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you need to manually close SmtpClient every time to avoid running out of resource, and you have to limit your multi thread number, otherwise you will use up TCP pool.

Comment: @Ray H 31 thanks for help can you plz tell how to do this sorry i am new and dont know much

Comment: after smtp.Send, use smtp.Close(). if you use multiple thread, you need to manage a thread pool, that would be a bit complicated. and any kind massive mail sending action is not recommended on web app, you should manage a queue to send them

Comment: ok thanks will try this. i am sending 5-10 email one time then other 5-10 emails

Comment: Its saying smtpclient doesnt contain definition for Close(); Does the Dispose() does the same? I can use smtp.Dispose()

Comment: should be, sorry for wrong info

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this on my project. Its working good. no any error appear after send 10-12 emails or more.

```
public static void Send(string from, string to, string cc, string subject, string message, string[] attachment, byte[] fileByte, string fileByteName)
        {
            string ccChar;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc) && cc.EndsWith(","))
                ccChar = cc.Remove(cc.Length - 1, 1);
            else
                ccChar = cc;

            if (smtp_address == "")
            {
                smtp_address = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp_address"];
                smtp_port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp_port"]);
                smtp_user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp_user"];
                smtp_password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp_password"];
                smtp_ssl = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp_ssl"]);
            }

            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, message);
            mm.Bcc.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAlertMonitor"]);

            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccChar)) mm.CC.Add(ccChar);

            if (fileByte.Length != 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileByteName))
            {
                mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(fileByte), fileByteName));
            }

            if (attachment != null)
            {
                foreach (string file in attachment)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
                    {
                        Attachment attc = new Attachment(file);
                        mm.Attachments.Add(attc);
                    }
                }
            }

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtp_address, smtp_port);
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtp_user, smtp_password);
            smtp.EnableSsl = smtp_ssl;

            smtp.Send(mm);
            InsertSendEmailLog(from, to, cc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAlertMonitor"], subject, message);
        }
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Can you describe a bit about code or simplify it as my code

Answer (score 0):

try like this and let me know.

```
        private static string smtp_address = "";
        private static int smtp_port = 587;
        private static string smtp_user = "";
        private static string smtp_password = "";
        private static bool smtp_ssl = false;
        private bool SendMassEmail(string from, string to, string cc, string subject, string message, string body)
        {
            smtp_address = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
            smtp_port = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
            smtp_user = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
            smtp_password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
            smtp_ssl = smtp_ssl;

            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, message);
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtp_address, smtp_port);
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtp_user, smtp_password);
            smtp.EnableSsl = smtp_ssl;

            smtp.Send(mm);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Ras Rass, I think the only difference from my code is smtp.enableSSl is false; Is it causing the problem? anyway will try this and let you know

Comment: I get a error if i make enableAsl=false; not working for me

Comment: SSL should be one and your not closing the client